# Delete Duplicate Records with Same Values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, performance

I have a TSQL statement that is taking several hours to run.  I'm sure I need to look into the import process to avoid duplicates being inserted but for the time being I'd just like to remove all records except one with duplicate values.  ParameterValueId is the primary key on the table but I have many duplicate entries that need to be deleted.  I only need one record for each ParameterId, SiteId, MeasurementDateTime, and ParameterValue.  Below is my current method for deleting duplicate records.  It finds all values that have a count > 1.  It then finds the first Id with those values and deletes all of the records with those values that don't match the first ID found by those values.  Besides the print statements is there a more efficient way of doing this.  Can I do a way with the cursor at all to improve performance?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @BeginningRecordCount INT
SET @BeginningRecordCount =
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM ParameterValues
)

DECLARE @ParameterId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @SiteId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @MeasurementDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @ParameterValue FLOAT


DECLARE CDuplicateValues CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
     [ParameterId]
    ,[SiteId]
    ,[MeasurementDateTime]
    ,[ParameterValue]
FROM [ParameterValues]
GROUP BY
     [ParameterId]
    ,[SiteId]
    ,[MeasurementDateTime]
    ,[ParameterValue]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

OPEN CDuplicateValues
FETCH NEXT FROM CDuplicateValues INTO
     @ParameterId
    ,@SiteId
    ,@MeasurementDateTime
    ,@ParameterValue

DECLARE @FirstParameterValueId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @DuplicateRecordsDeleting INT
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
    SET @FirstParameterValueId =
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 ParameterValueId
        FROM ParameterValues
        WHERE
                ParameterId = @ParameterId
            AND SiteId = @SiteId
            AND MeasurementDateTime = @MeasurementDateTime
            AND ParameterValue = @ParameterValue
    )

    SET @DuplicateRecordsDeleting =
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM ParameterValues
        WHERE
                ParameterId = @ParameterId
            AND SiteId = @SiteId
            AND MeasurementDateTime = @MeasurementDateTime
            AND ParameterValue = @ParameterValue
            AND ParameterValueId <> @FirstParameterValueId
    )

    PRINT 'DELETING ' + CAST(@DuplicateRecordsDeleting AS NVARCHAR(50))
        + ' records with values ParameterId : ' + CAST(@ParameterId AS NVARCHAR(50))
        + ', SiteId : ' + CAST (@SiteId AS NVARCHAR(50))
        + ', MeasurementDateTime : ' + CAST(@MeasurementDateTime AS NVARCHAR(50))
        + ', ParameterValue : ' + CAST(@ParameterValue AS NVARCHAR(50))

    DELETE FROM ParameterValues
        WHERE
                ParameterId = @ParameterId
            AND SiteId = @SiteId
            AND MeasurementDateTime = @MeasurementDateTime
            AND ParameterValue = @ParameterValue
            AND ParameterValueId <> @FirstParameterValueId

    FETCH NEXT FROM CDuplicateValues INTO
         @ParameterId
        ,@SiteId
        ,@MeasurementDateTime
        ,@ParameterValue
END
CLOSE CDuplicateValues
DEALLOCATE CDuplicateValues

DECLARE @EndingRecordCount INT
SET @EndingRecordCount =
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM ParameterValues
)

PRINT 'Beginning Record Count   :   ' + CAST(@BeginningRecordCount AS NVARCHAR(50))
PRINT 'Ending Record Count      :   ' + CAST(@EndingRecordCount AS NVARCHAR(50))
PRINT 'Total Records Deleted    :   ' + CAST((@BeginningRecordCount - @EndingRecordCount) AS NVARCHAR(50))

SET NOCOUNT OFF

PRINT 'RUN THE COMMIT OR ROLLBACK STATEMENT AFTER VERIFYING DATA.'
--COMMIT
--ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use option with [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [OVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause. [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).. INTO clause saves the information from rows affected by an DELETE statement into @delParameterValues table. Further, in the body of procedure, you can use this table to print the affected rows.

```
DECLARE @delParameterValues TABLE
 (
  ParameterId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
  SiteId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
  MeasurementDateTime DATETIME,
  ParameterValue FLOAT,
  DeletedRecordCount int
  )

;WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ParameterId],[SiteId],[MeasurementDateTime],[ParameterValue] ORDER BY 1/0) AS rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [ParameterId],[SiteId],[MeasurementDateTime],[ParameterValue]) AS cnt
 FROM [ParameterValues]
 )
 DELETE cte
 OUTPUT DELETED.[ParameterId], 
        DELETED.[SiteId], 
        DELETED.[MeasurementDateTime],
        DELETED.[ParameterValue],
        DELETED.cnt INTO @delParameterValues
 WHERE rn != 1

 SELECT DISTINCT *
 FROM @delParameterValues
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8484e/1)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in a single sql:

```
DELETE p FROM ParameterValues p
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ParameterId, SiteId, MeasurementDateTime, ParameterValue, MAX(ParameterValueId) AS MAX_PARAM
 FROM ParameterValues
 GROUP BY ParameterId, SiteId, MeasurementDateTime, ParameterValue
) m
ON m.ParameterId = p.ParameterId
  AND m.SiteId = p.SiteId
  AND m.MeasurementDateTime = p.MeasurementDateTime
  AND m.ParameterValue = p.ParameterValue
  AND m.MAX_PARAM = p.ParameterValueId
WHERE m.ParameterId IS NULL
```

Of course it will not print the output, but you can still print the rows before and after

Comment: Don't you want a HAVING in the `m` subtable to make sure you are only getting records that are actually duplicates? That will delete a single record from each domain whether it's a duplicate or not.

Comment: `WHERE m.ParameterId IS NULL` is taking care of it

Comment: Anyway, I suggest that the OP convert this DELETE statement to a SELECT statement and run it to see what is selected. Whatever selected will be deleted

Comment: I am getting an error with the where clause m.MAX_PARAM = p.ParameterValueId.  Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Operand data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for max operator.  It's a SQL Server 2005 server is that a SQL Server 2008 only expression?

Comment: Actually I think the error is occuring here "MAX(ParameterValueId)"  Is there a first or top 1 equivalent?

Comment: Fixed by changing to MAX(CAST(ParameterValueId AS NVARCHAR(50)))

Comment: Upvoted answer and it does work but I went with other answer as it deletes and outputs in the same statemnet

Comment: BTW, you've asked for performance. With CTE you would not get any performance improvements, I believe